# Blurring a picture (Python, Jython, picture editing)

Tags: python, image-manipulation, jython

Trying to blur a picture in Jython.  What I have does run but does not return a blurred picture.  I'm kinda at a loss of what is wrong with it.

**FINAL (WORKING) CODE EDITED IN BELOW.  THANKS FOR HELP GUYS!**

def main():

```
pic= makePicture( pickAFile() )
show( pic )
blurAmount=10
makeBlurredPicture(pic,blurAmount)
show(makeBlurredPicture(pic,blurAmount))
```

def makeBlurredPicture(pic,blurAmount):

```
w=getWidth(pic)
h=getHeight(pic)
blurPic= makeEmptyPicture( w-blurAmount, h )
for px in getPixels(blurPic):
  x=getX(px)
  y=getY(px)
  if (x+blurAmount<w):
     rTotal=0
     gTotal=0
     bTotal=0
     for i in range(0,blurAmount):
         origpx=getPixel(pic,x+i,y)
         rTotal=rTotal+getRed(origpx)
         gTotal=gTotal+getGreen(origpx)
         bTotal=bTotal+getBlue(origpx)
     rAverage=(rTotal/blurAmount)
     gAverage=(gTotal/blurAmount)
     bAverage=(bTotal/blurAmount)

     setRed(px,rAverage)
     setGreen(px,gAverage)
     setBlue(px,bAverage)
return blurPic
```

The pseudo-code was as such : makeBlurredPicture(picture, blur_amount)
get width and height of picture and make an empty picture  with the dimensions 
(w-blur_amount, h ) call this blurPic

```
for loop, looping through all the pixels (in blurPic)
    get and save x and y locations of the pixel
     #make sure you are not too close to edge (x+blur) is less than width 
            Intialize rTotal, gTotal, and bTotal to 0
             # add up the rgb values for all the pixels in the blur
             For loop that loops (blur_amount) times
                    rTotal= rTotal +the red pixel amount of the picture (input argument)               at the location  (x+loop number,y)     then same for green and blue
             find the average of red,green, blue values, this is just  rTotal/blur_amount (same for green, and blue)
             set the red value of blurPic pixel to the redAverage  (same for green and    blue)
return blurPic
```

Comment: Could it be because you're calling show() on the original pic and not the blurred one?

Comment: I figured return would show it. :/ How do show it properly?  I tried putting show(blurPic) at the end of the main() function but that wouldn't work.

Comment: Just a guess: I'm suspicious of your divisions: `rTotal/blurAmount`.  Are both rTotal and blurAmount integers?  If so, you're doing a truncating division (integer result), when you probably want a true division, with floating-point result.  Edit:  no, scrap that.  Integer division looks fine here.

Comment: I feel like it's just missing something very basic, like the wrong thing under the wrong loop or one line left out.

Comment: In the innermost loop, rename px to something else.  I think you're overwriting the px from the outer loop.

Comment: There's also an off-by-one error in this code, though I don't think that's responsible for your current problems.  As it stands, the right-most column of the original picture never gets used in the blurred image.  `w - blurAmount` should be `w - blurAmount + 1`, and the `x + blurAmount < w` check should be `x + blurAmount <= w`.  Remember that `range(0, blurAmount)` only goes up to `blurAmount - 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are overwriting the variable `px` from the outer loop which is the pixel in the blurred image with a pixel value from the original image.
So just replace your inner loop with:

```
for i in range(0,blurAmount):
    origPx=getPixel(pic,x+i,y)
    rTotal=rTotal+getRed(origPx)
    gTotal=gTotal+getGreen(origPx)
    bTotal=bTotal+getBlue(origPx)
```

In order to show the blurred picture change the last line in you `main` to

```
show( makeBlurredPicture(pic,blurAmount) )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This was it.  Correct code edited in main post.  Upvoted, Checked, etc.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way to do it:

```
import ImageFilter

def filterBlur(im):

    im1 = im.filter(ImageFilter.BLUR)

    im1.save("BLUR" + ext)

filterBlur(im1)
```

For a complete reference to the Image Library See: http://www.riisen.dk/dop/pil.html

Comment: I wish it would be that easy but I'm a student and the Prof wants it done longways.

Answer (score 0):

```
def blur_image(image, radius):
    blur = image.filter(ImageFilter.GaussianBlur(radius))
    image.paste(blur,(0,0))
    return image
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While answers are always appreciated, this question was asked 6 years ago, and already had an accepted solution. Please try to avoid 'bumping' questions to the top by providing answers to them, unless the question was not already marked as resolved, or you found a dramatically better alternative approach to the problem :)